# Struts2 :Re-write URL in Struts2 interceptor

Tags: jsp, struts2

I want to append a parameter to the URL after the execution of an action i.e in interceptor.

How do I do this?

Here,Struts.xml

```
     <action name="reviewpolist" class="purchaseOrderAction" method="getReviewPOList">
         <result name="success">reviewpolist.jsp </result>
     </action>
```

my current URL is-

```
localhost":8080/FLO_OSIII/po/jsp/reviewpolist.action?s=185366951
```

now i want to add parameter `GetFlg=1`  to URl   like,

```
localhost:8080/FLO_OSIII/po/jsp/reviewpolist.action?s=185366951&GetFlg=1
```

after action execution.
Action -

```
public String getreviewpolist()throws Throwable{    

    //  here my processing code.
    return SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Why? What's the point of doing that? After the action has executed the URL won't make any difference. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

To add parameter in the url you should build the URL using [`s:url`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/url-tag.html) tag or use [`UrlHelper`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/util/UrlHelper.html) that allows you to do it programmatically. For example

```
<s:url action="reviewpolist" includeParams="get">
    <s:param name="GetFlg" value="%{'1'}" />
</s:url>
```

Comment: After the action has executed the URL won't make any difference.its correct. but i want to add parameter in same URL.

Comment: It does, use the params tag like explained here.