# Port number changing in URL while redirecting to different JSP pages

Tags: struts2, websphere

We have an application URL
xxx.xxx.com and post Authentication, user request goes to load balancer URL and there are 2 websphere instances behind the load balancer URL.

load balancer URL is: host.xxx.com:21758 and the individual instances are
instance1.xxx.com:61158, instance2.xxx.com:21758

Issue what we are facing is post login and when the request goes into instance1, URL in the address bar is changing to host.xxx.com:61158 i.e. load balancer URL & Instace1 port number.

In the code we are not using any HTTP parameters like Host or any port number specifically

Environment is
Websphere 8.5.5.9 server, Struts 2.3.X and JSPs

```
<action name="home">
    <result>/jsp/login.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="login" class="com.XXX.YYYY.admin.web.struts.action.LoginAction">
    <result name="success">/jsp/adminhome.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/jsp/error.jsp</result>
    <result name="home" type="chain">home</result>
</action>
```

When request comes in, LoginAction gets invoked and post some validation, "Success" string is returned. Based on that string another JSP needs to be shown up. But instead of that, URL in the address bar is getting changed.

URL should not be changed

Comment: S2 doesn't know anything about load balancers/etc. This is most likely an issue with your networking infrastructure.

Comment: Any idea about what does S2 do when navigating/redirecting to a different page? Like does it use, httpRequest.getRequestURL() to get the current URL (or) Host URL etc.

Comment: The port shouldn't be exposed on the S2 side; that's not unique to S2. All sorts of apps are hooked up to load balancers and you don't see the port number on the client side. Port numbers, session mgmt, etc. are handled after the app itself.

Comment: Thank you, the issue that I am facing is, for some reason when the request is handled by instance-1 which has port number different to f5 (load balancer), in that case the URL in address bar is changing. From code perspective, I am not adding any statement as such to get port number or host etc. I am not quite sure about how code developed in Struts and deployed on Websphere server knows about the port#

Comment: Port number is generated by default, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25077896/573032

Comment: After lot of debugging and browsing, I found out that Websphere by default takes host name and instance (i.e. server) port number. There are some custom attributes that needs to be added on Websphere side to take the load balancer host name port number.

Please refer below link
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK55330